# How much penalty can consumers get in USA or other country in Europe?

Tags: penalty, counterfeiting

According to Article 55 in "consumer protection law including 2013 amendments(Chinese law)" :

> Where proprietors fraudulently provide goods or services, they shall follow consumers' requests to increase the compensation for their losses,
> with the increased compensation being three times the price paid by a consumer for purchased goods or the services received,
> or 500 yuan if the increase as calculated before is less than 500 yuan, except as otherwise provided for by the law. Where the law provides otherwise, follow those provisions.

If i bought a fake goods in seller's store at price 100 (200)yuan,i can apply for 500 (600)yuan ,the seller pay me 500(600)yuan for selling counterfeit goods.It is the penalty.

How much penalty can consumers get in the simple scene in USA or other country in Europe?

Comment: You misread the law a little. As far as it is written, the law pretty much says "If you were defrauded, you get 3 times the price you paid or 500 yuan, whichever is greater." That is not a consumer penalty, but the punitive damages for **fraud**.

Comment: In the U.S. this is governed by state law which varies from state to state and may not be available at all in some states. In the E.U. this would be governed by national law, not E.U. law and again, can vary considerably from one country to another. Also, the punitive damages are not automatic, you have to win a lawsuit first. It is rare to have someone agree to a settlement without going to court that awards you that fine.

Answer (score 3):

[england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales)

Generally, the consumer is only entitled to a refund of what he paid for the goods.

In English law, 'punitive damages' - an award in excess of the loss - are rare.

It is a criminal offence to sell counterfeit goods - [Unauthorised use of trade mark, &c. in relation to goods, s92 Trade Marks Act 1994](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1994/26/section/92). The maximum penalty is up to ten years in prison or an unlimited fine (paid to the state).

Comment: The law cited by OP is actually about goods or service **fraud** not just a refund.

Answer (score 1):

### A contract entered into as a result of fraud is void

That means the consumer is entitled to a refund of the monies already paid. They would not generally be entitled to additional damages.

### Prosecution of fraud is a matter for the government

If the consumer were to report the vendor, the government might launch a criminal prosecution. This could result in gaol time or a serious fine.